# text.compareTo() what does this means?

Tags: java

```
String ntext;
ntext = something;
String currentLine;
currentLine = something;

while(ntext.compareTo(currentLine) != 0){
    //some condition
     }
```

> Here i want to know what that compareto actually do.
>   One more questin what we can use to compare two objects?

Comment: It does what it says on tin. What are the types of `ntext` and `currentLine`?

Comment: There is documentation that you can read.... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String- if this is a String, or the general https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-

Comment: @Tunaki can you think of any reason why `equals` wouldn't work? Something related to larger character sets for example?

Comment: That could be written as `while (!ntext.equals(currentLine)) {` - does that make its meaning more clear?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Nope. Well except if the class is broken to begin with and doesn't have consistent `equals` and `compareTo` :). (it is *strongly recommended, but not strictly required*...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those variables are strings (i assume so) it checks if they are equal, returns 0 if so, and another number if not. See the JavaDoc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

More specifically, it goes through both strings character by character. When it finds a string of one that is not equal to the other, it returns a number representing whether the differing character is more than, less than, or equal to the corresponding character in the other string.